# Can I run Ubuntu 17.10 on VirtualBox on my Lenovo G580 laptop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

First of all, I want to say that I'm a beginner with Linux or its distros, so please don't laugh about my knowledge, also my English 8).

My question is:

Can I install `Ubuntu 17.10` on `VirtualBox` on my `Lenovo G580` laptop without having any problems with `BIOS`? On their webpage, it says that `Ubuntu 17.10` has an issue with certain Lenovo laptops.

Since mine is `G580` I can't find this model on their list of affected laptops (or maybe I don't know how to search).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'm assuming you're using Windows operating system with virtual box installed in it. If you're running ubuntu in virtual box in Windows OS then it will acts as a virtual OS in Windows, which means it won't go to bios level and it will work inside your windows OS.

So, there is a probability it will not effect you at all but if you're thinking to install ubuntu in your laptop as dual boot(alongside windows) or standalone operating system(only ubuntu is installed as primary OS) then I suggest you to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS instead because it is stable and Long Term Supported (LTS) than Ubuntu 17.10 which is beta version(Testing phase for developers and hard-core ubuntu fan) which is good idea for beginners.

And no problem, we all are beginners at some point.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm using Windows. Your answer is what I was looking for. Thank you again!